# Making a Button invisible in its click handler

Tags: vba, forms, button

In my subform (VBA in ms-access) there is a button called "Test" and this button has to be set invisible after it was clicked.

So I tried:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
    'Do some stuff
    Me.Test.Visible = False
End Sub
```

But this does not work. It raises an error because it is not possible to make a button invisible, which has the focus. Unfortunately the button is the only button on the form (the other controls are lables). As the button is in a subform, I tried to set the focus to a button in the parent:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
    'Do some stuff
    call me.parent.schclose.SetFocus
    Me.Test.Visible = False
End Sub
```

But this did not work either. 'call me.parent.schclose.SetFocus' does not raise an error but 'Me.Test.Visible = False' does like before.

So, how to make the button invisible?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is expand your user form and add a button that is visible by default.  Let's say currently your user form has  height of 300 and a width of 300.  Expand the form to be 500X500 and place the new button on the bottom right of that form (keep the visible property set to Yes).  Next add this code to the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.Height = 300
Me.Width = 300
End Sub
```

Now when you click on your test button it will be invisible and the new button will still be hidden because it's not within the height you set above.

Comment: Also, you don't need to change the focus anymore on your Test_click.  The only thing you will need is just Me.Test.Visible = False

Comment: This seems to work. But its a very nasty workaround. I finally used another method (which was inspired by your answer)

Comment: @Gener4tor what was that method?

Comment: see below. I use a "empty read-only edit field with a transperent boarder".

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by the answer of VBA_SQL_Programmer I created a empty read-only edit field with a transperent boarder (which means it is basicly invisible) in my form to set the focus to.

So my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()
    'Do some stuff
    call me.invisibleTextBox.SetFocus
    Me.Test.Visible = False
End Sub
```

This works without manipulating the size of the form.

But there is a problem too, because as the focus is set to the textBox, the user can see a blinking cursor.

Comment: I think we will have to agree to disagree on the best approach.  Setting the height and width is in my opinion best practice anyways because if you don't then the form can open up in weird sizes on different computer/monitor setups.  Which can make it look unprofessional

Comment: This form is a subform which is embedded in some other forms. So the parent form might set the size too.